# Saslauthd - slow response, client timeout

Tags: saslauthd

We use saslauthd 2.1.27 with postfix and rimap authentication. We experience a strange issue after an update: terribly slow response times soon after a restart.

If the saslauthd process is restarted, the response is fast, under one second.
Then a few seconds later response is around one second.
After one minute several seconds, and after several minutes up to several minutes.

While testsaslauthd always gives a response after a certain time, the mailing client's timeout.

The imap servers respond normally, so it seems to be an issue with saslauthd.
Anyone ha sany ideas how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that setting threads to 0 solved the issue.

> -n threads
> Use threads processes for responding to authentication queries. (default: 5) A value of zero will indicate that saslauthd should fork an individual process for each connection. This can solve leaks that occur in some deployments..